# Meaning of irregular error

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, finite-differences

In a paper I've read it is said that the error of the finite difference scheme is not regular since small changes in the exact solution can lead to big changes in the approximate solution.
Can someone give me a reference where the meaning of an irregular error of an approximation scheme is accurately explained? I haven't been able to find it in my usual documents.

Comment: The choice of words is unusual. You should include a link to the relevant paper so that we can understand the context.

Comment: The paper is "Efficient Algorithms for Diffusion-Generated Motion by Mean Curvature" of Ruuth and it is found here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999198960259. And it is found on page 607 in the second last line.